# Spring Java + Set template file as style sheet

Tags: java, css, spring

I need a way to set a template file (styles.vm) as a style sheet file (styles.css) at compile time.  The reason is simple, I need to "environmental-ize" background image paths in all my style sheets.  For instance:

```
.bg { background:url('$(static.image.path)graphic_background.png') }
```

Where $(static.image.path) is a variable found in a property file unique to each environment.  Any suggestions?

Note: I've created a Servlet Listener that parses all styles sheets and injects the path dynamically, but feel this solution is overkill.

Comment: Which build tool are you using?

Comment: @RaviH - Maven is the build tool we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven resource filtering plugin for dynamically replacing the variable place holders at build time. See [Maven Resource Filter Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for documentation.

Comment: Precisely what I needed.  Once I had this direction, I googled further regarding Maven Filtering and CSS specifically and found this article which covers just that: http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering